# com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException:

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am changed all gradle version to 27.0.2 still its showing issues and that app.compact gradle also showing in redline.I cant able to run the application

[image]

gradle.file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
    // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
    // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
    // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    }
}



// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Required for 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.1.1'
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        mavenCentral();
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.1.0'
}

// Configuration properties. Set these via environment variables, build-extras.gradle, or gradle.properties.
// Refer to: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html
ext {
    apply from: 'CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
    // The value for android.compileSdkVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvCompileSdkVersion')) {
        cdvCompileSdkVersion = null;
    }
    // The value for android.buildToolsVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildToolsVersion')) {
        cdvBuildToolsVersion = null;
    }
    // Sets the versionCode to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCode')) {
        cdvVersionCode = null
    }
    // Sets the minSdkVersion to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvMinSdkVersion')) {
        cdvMinSdkVersion = null
    }
    // Whether to build architecture-specific APKs.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildMultipleApks')) {
        cdvBuildMultipleApks = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for release signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for debug signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // Set by build.js script.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildArch')) {
        cdvBuildArch = null
    }

    // Plugin gradle extensions can append to this to have code run at the end.
    cdvPluginPostBuildExtras = []
}

// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS START
apply from: "cordova-plugin-admobpro/base-build.gradle"
apply from: "cordova-hot-code-push-plugin/base-chcp.gradle"
apply from: "phonegap-plugin-push/base-push.gradle"
apply from: "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/base-barcodescanner.gradle"
apply from: "cordova-plugin-geofence/base-build.gradle"
// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS END

def hasBuildExtras = file('build-extras.gradle').exists()
if (hasBuildExtras) {
    apply from: 'build-extras.gradle'
}

// Set property defaults after extension .gradle files.
if (ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion = privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
}
if (ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
}
if (ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('debug-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = 'debug-signing.properties'
}
if (ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('release-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = 'release-signing.properties'
}

// Cast to appropriate types.
ext.cdvBuildMultipleApks = cdvBuildMultipleApks == null ? false : cdvBuildMultipleApks.toBoolean();
ext.cdvMinSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
ext.cdvVersionCode = cdvVersionCode == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvVersionCode)

def computeBuildTargetName(debugBuild) {
    def ret = 'assemble'
    if (cdvBuildMultipleApks && cdvBuildArch) {
        def arch = cdvBuildArch == 'arm' ? 'armv7' : cdvBuildArch
        ret += '' + arch.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + arch.substring(1);
    }
    return ret + (debugBuild ? 'Debug' : 'Release')
}

// Make cdvBuild a task that depends on the debug/arch-sepecific task.
task cdvBuildDebug
cdvBuildDebug.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(true)
}

task cdvBuildRelease
cdvBuildRelease.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(false)
}

task cdvPrintProps << {
    println('cdvCompileSdkVersion=' + cdvCompileSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildToolsVersion=' + cdvBuildToolsVersion)
    println('cdvVersionCode=' + cdvVersionCode)
    println('cdvMinSdkVersion=' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildMultipleApks=' + cdvBuildMultipleApks)
    println('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvBuildArch=' + cdvBuildArch)
    println('computedVersionCode=' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
    android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
        println('computed' + flavor.name.capitalize() + 'VersionCode=' + flavor.versionCode)
    }
}

android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048m"
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")
        multiDexEnabled true
        if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
            minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
        }
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
    if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
        productFlavors {
            armv7 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode * 10 + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", ""
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode * 10 + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "x86", ""
                }
            }
            all {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "all", ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /*

    ELSE NOTHING! DON'T MESS WITH THE VERSION CODE IF YOU DON'T HAVE TO!

    else if (!cdvVersionCode) {
      def minSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion ?: privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("minSdkVersion")
      // Vary versionCode by the two most common API levels:
      // 14 is ICS, which is the lowest API level for many apps.
      // 20 is Lollipop, which is the lowest API level for the updatable system webview.
      if (minSdkVersion >= 20) {
        defaultConfig.versionCode += 9
      } else if (minSdkVersion >= 14) {
        defaultConfig.versionCode += 8
      }
    }
    */
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
                keyAlias = ""
                keyPassword = "__unset"
                // And these must be set to non-empty in order to have the signing step added to the task graph.
                storeFile = null
                storePassword = "__unset"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
    }
    if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
        addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    // debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    // releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    implementation project(path: ':CordovaLib')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.8'
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.14@aar'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
}

def promptForReleaseKeyPassword() {
    if (!cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        return;
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key store password: ')
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key password: ');
    }
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    taskGraph.getAllTasks().each() { task ->
        if (task.name == 'validateReleaseSigning' || task.name == 'validateSigningRelease') {
            promptForReleaseKeyPassword()
        }
    }
}

def addSigningProps(propsFilePath, signingConfig) {
    def propsFile = file(propsFilePath)
    def props = new Properties()
    propsFile.withReader { reader ->
        props.load(reader)
    }

    def storeFile = new File(props.get('key.store') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'storeFile'))
    if (!storeFile.isAbsolute()) {
        storeFile = RelativePath.parse(true, storeFile.toString()).getFile(propsFile.getParentFile())
    }
    if (!storeFile.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException('Keystore file does not exist: ' + storeFile.getAbsolutePath())
    }
    signingConfig.keyAlias = props.get('key.alias') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'keyAlias')
    signingConfig.keyPassword = props.get('keyPassword', props.get('key.alias.password', signingConfig.keyPassword))
    signingConfig.storeFile = storeFile
    signingConfig.storePassword = props.get('storePassword', props.get('key.store.password', signingConfig.storePassword))
    def storeType = props.get('storeType', props.get('key.store.type', ''))
    if (!storeType) {
        def filename = storeFile.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (filename.endsWith('.p12') || filename.endsWith('.pfx')) {
            storeType = 'pkcs12'
        } else {
            storeType = signingConfig.storeType // "jks"
        }
    }
    signingConfig.storeType = storeType
}

for (def func : cdvPluginPostBuildExtras) {
    func()
}

 build-extras.gradle as:
   //     ext.postBuildExtras = { ... code here ... }
if (hasProperty('postBuildExtras')) {
    postBuildExtras()
}
```

i even `cleaned and rebuild` the project
i added `multidexenabled=true` and all gradle plugin versions 27.0.2 but still i cant run.

Comment: Do `alt+enter` `no-inspection` is there any `runtime` crash occurred

Comment: invalidate caches/restart?

Comment: but still app is not running while taking build its showing this issue"com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException:
"

Comment: Update your firebase-ui library to 3.2.2 and use support 27.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Change to this version

implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.0"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.0"

Answer (score -1):

There is a conflict between some of the libraries that are using support library 27.1.0 and some using 27.0.2

Update all of the support library references from 27.0.2 to 27.1.0 in your build.gradle file and it will fix the problem.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'

------------------

implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
```

Comment: but still app is not running while taking build its showing this issue"com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException:
"